# Pop-unders in Chrome Canary 29?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, popup, popup-blocker

How can one generate a pop-under in Chrome Canary 29?

See also issues reported on GitHub:

- [jquery-popunder #33](https://github.com/hpbuniat/jquery-popunder/issues/33)
- [js-popunder #14](https://github.com/tuki/js-popunder/issues/14)

**Disclaimer:** Yes, pop-unders suck. The same with pop-ups. In fact, I advocate that when designing for the web, one should not think about windows at all, and better avoid things like setting the `target` attribute of a link (which is [illegal](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/2004/xhtml-faq#target) in XHTML strict, by the way). Anyhow, not in all projects I have the last word.

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if the Google chieftains have made this impossible.  Yay for them.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the rules for popups are as follows:

- If you do a window.open outside of a user triggered event, it will be blocked, and display a given message.  In general, popups will work transparently as part of a click event.
- If you want a pop-over, leave it be...
- if you want a pop-under, simply window.focus() after you do your window.open(...);

```
var w = window.open(...);
window.focus();
```

Note: The target attribute will still work in a browser.  Though, you wouldn't want a link to pop under your current page.

Comment: `var w = window.open(...); window.focus();` That doesn't even work in Chrome 27. Try it right away in the developer console: `window.onclick = function () { var w = window.open('http://stackoverflow.com', 'StackOverflow', 'height=200,width=200'); window.setTimeout(function () { window.focus(); }, 1000); }` Click inside the window for testing: A window pops up, but it does not go to the background. User interaction is necessary to prevent the pop-up blocker from kicking in.